# how to know when the user clicks on any application in android?

Tags: android

I am making an application.  I want to know when the user clicks on any application in android, I want to make a toast.  For example  there's a service class working behind that check box.  If the check box is true and now service is started which is on background.

For example if the user clicks on messages I want to make a toast that users clicks messages.  User can click on any application which is installed in the android system.

Answer (score 1):

Write a code which uses a combination of AlarmManager and Service. Trigger the service at regular intervals.

Write this in the service:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
```

This will return you the info about the foregroundActivity thats currently on the top.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible unless you create your own launcher application. Then you can do whatever you want between the user click and app launch.

Alternatively, you may start a background `Service` monitoring the currently running processes. This way you will be able to know which application is currently in the foreground and when it changes - you can deduct that user launched a new one. This is, however a rather complex solution.

So the short answer is no, it is not directly possible. There are only solutions which can mimic the feature you described.